# Make directory from generated hash output

Tags: bash, random, hash

This bash command generates a short hash that I'd like to use to name a directory created with `mkdir`:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1
```

Which (I think):

1. Creates a [random-ish](http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/) number
2. Limits the character set with [tr](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/12/linux-tr-command/) (translation)
3. [Folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28Unix%29)/wraps each line of output at 32 characters
4. Limits output to one line starting at the start with [head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head_%28Unix%29)

I can simply copy the output of this command and paste it into a `mkdir` command, but how would it be done in a single command?

I tried adding `| mkdir` and `| mkdir -p` to then end, thinking I could pipe the output to `mkdir`.

Comment: Use `mktemp -d` if directory name length of 32 character not mandatory

Comment: and if 32 is mandatory: `mktemp -d XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` will give you 32 random alphanumeric characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) to insert output of one command into another

```
mkdir $(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
```

Some programs like `mkdir` and `rm` so you cannot pipe stdin to them. You can also use `xargs` to pass stdin to command

Comment: Would you mind explaining  what is happening there with the dollar sign and parentheses?

Answer (score 1):

mkdir does not look for a directory name on it's stdin, which is why `| mkdir` doesn't work.

@Rozuur's answer is very straightforward.

Another option is to use `xargs`:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1 | xargs mkdir
```

xargs reads lines from stdin, and *appends* those as arguments to the given command.

Comment: great to know. I see `xargs` around often. hadn't RTFM on it though.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mktemp`:

```
mktemp -d `printf "%0.sX" {1..32}`
```

Here `printf` generates template string with repeating 32 times 'X' character (thanx @glennjackman for the tip)